# How to add external javascript file in React's component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

could anyone say "How to insert an external JS file in my **react app's component**" ?

I want to insert js file in my **navbar.js** this is my component also.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav>
                <div class="hamburger">
                    <div class="line"></div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav-links">
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        );
    }
}
```

And my app.Js file

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from "./components/navbar";


function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my external js that placed inside of the externel-js folder.

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    navLinks.classList.toggle("open");
    links.forEach(link => {
        link.classList.toggle("fade");
    });
});
```

This is my folder.

[image: My folder looks like]

Comment: Where is the file... How it looks like? You can just import it...

Comment: Now, I included my external js file in question. please refer
If i imported, I got an error.

Comment: Your external JavaScript file doing classic DOM stuff? you can use ref to access this properties

Comment: I cant understand. Could you explain deeply?

Comment: All the code in your external.js could/should be done in React

Answer (score 0):

You can load the `external.js` file in **component** with the help of **DOM Method**.

```
componentDidMount () {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "/path/to/external.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

This should work, Happy coding.

Comment: Where I add this? navbar.js or app.js?

Comment: Please add this in Navbar.js.

Comment: If this was helpful to you, please upvote the answer.

Comment: @ParvezMemon could you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73311515/i-am-using-webpack-5-in-react-html-file-i-want-to-read-external-file-which-si i tried your solution but it did not work as react does not allow files other than src folder