# I am using webpack 5, In react , html file i want to read external file which sits in build folder.How can i do it?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using webpack 5, In react , html file i want to read external file(lets say json file) which sits in build folder.How can i do it? We have a public folder where our index.html sits, while creating of build folder in ci cd process we are copying all our env variables and creating text file.How can it be read from that index.html so that i can put it to process.env

Comment: what file type do you want to link, also what have you tried

Comment: lets say json.how to read logic i know but just that react does not allow files other than the files in src folder.

Comment: add `"resolveJsonModule": true,` to `compilerOptions` in tsconfig.json

Comment: It does not help @DeanVanGreunen